# Filtering PageList in Manager by User & Hooks

Tags: piranha-cms

I want to make Piranha CMS manager screen to list pages which are created by the logged-in user only. I thought I should use PageListModelLoaded hook to achieve this and wrote this code in global.asax.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
   RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   Hooks.Manager.PageListModelLoaded += (controller, menu, model) =>
   {
       Guid user_id =  controller.User.GetProfile().Id;
       model.Pages = model.Pages.Where(p => p.CreatedBy == user_id).ToList();     
   };
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as I expected, Manager lists all pages even if I see that count of model.Pages is equal to zero through debugging step by step. I appreciate if someone help me see what my fault is.

Regards,
Umit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication manager of Piranha CMS uses **FormsAuthentication**, so the correct way of getting the user id of the logged in user is:

```
var user_id = new Guid(controller.User.Identity.Name);
```

Best regards!

**EDIT 2015-01-16**

Ok, so I took a closer look at your question. The page list view is actually fed two collections through its view model. One flat list of pages `model.Pages` and one hierarchical collection `model.SiteMap`. You can see the call here for the rendering of the tree-structure:

https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha/blob/2.2.4/Piranha/Areas/Manager/Views/Page/Index.cshtml#L178

The reason for this is that pages are displayed in a tree-structure (SiteMap), but when you type something in the search-field a flat list is returned (Pages). In order to filter the view you need to filter both collections.

/Håkan

Comment: Thanks @HåkanEdling but your code for getting the user_id returns the same guid as the one I wrote in my question. The guid returned may be right or wrong, the real problem is even if the count of model.pages returned from Where condition is 0, pages are still listed in the manager. (I am using the sample app which came with PiranhaCmsMvc nuget package, In the database, there is only one page created by user guid {ca19d4e7-92f0-42f6-926a-68413bbdafbc}, logged-in user's guid is {309d6b3a-26c7-4cfb-a71e-6e1b83993960} and that one page is still listed)

Comment: Thanks @HåkanEdling, your edited answer solved my problem. I even tried filtering for only SiteMap and removing filter for Pages and saw that typing the right words resulted the filtered page to appear. Maybe this can be used as a way to create secret pages, only users who have the secret word and know to search for it can see the secret pages :)